# Query to exclude related objects in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a query to get objects which are not related to each other?

For example, my Objects table has a Relation column to the same Table (Objects), let's call it "connected". I want to get a list of all objects which are not related to objectId "abc", or in other words where "connected" doesn't include object "abc".

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Android:
ParseQuery<Object> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Object.class);
query.whereNotEqualTo("connected", "abc");

iOS
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Object"];
[query whereKey:@"connected" notEqualTo:@"abc"];

PHP
$query = new ParseQuery("Object");
$query->notEqualTo("connected", "abc");

JavaScript
var Object = Parse.Object.extend("Object");
var query = new Parse.Query(Object);
query.notEqualTo("connected", "abc");
```